# Counting the number of vowels in a string

Tags: c++

I am writing a function that returns the number of vowels for a given string, here is the code:

```
int isVowel(string sequence)
{   
    int numberOfVowels = 0;         //Initialize number of vowels to zero
    string vowels = "aeiouAEIOU";   //Possible vowels, including capitals
    for (int i = 0; i <= sequence.length(); i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j <= vowels.length(); j++)
        {
            if (sequence[i] == vowels[j])
            {
                numberOfVowels += 1;
            }
        }
    }
    return numberOfVowels;
}
```

This returns answers that are off by one.  For example, input of "a" returns 2, input of "aa" returns 3, etc.

Comment: I suggest you learn some debugging skills. You can either use a source-level debugger such as gdb or the one built into your IDE or you can add cout statements to print the values of variables.

Comment: The name `isVowel()` strongly suggests a similarity with functions from `<ctype.h>` (`cctype`).  These test a single character.  Maybe your function should be renamed `numVowels()` or some such name, emphasizing that it counts the vowels in a string.

Comment: Maybe you should break the inner loop when you find a match; you don't need to test the other characters.  Maybe you should optimize on `e` before `a` since there are more e's in running text than a's, usually?

Comment: consider using [`std::count_if()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/count) instead of a manual loop, eg: `const std::string vowels = "aeiouAEIOU"; bool isVowel(char c) { return (vowels.find(c) != std::string::npos); } int numVowels(const std::string sequence) { return std::count_if(sequence.begin(), sequence.end(), isVowel); }`

Answer (score 4):

```
i <= sequence.length()
```

`<=` is almost never correct in any for loop since C++ uses 0-based indices. Instead, you should do

```
i < sequence.length()
```

Comment: I figured it was something like that, thanks for the input!

Comment: And, intriguingly, the problem is that the null byte at the ends of the strings are being compared, and they're equal, so it is counted.  That isn't an obvious consequence of the mistake.

Comment: Yes that is very subtle indeed, I sometimes forget that strings are terminated in memory by a null byte and that this does not get included when calculating string.length()